# net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING redirecting WP Login page

Tags: wordpress, chunked-encoding

I have a plugin on my three Wordpress sites called Launchkey. Launchkey removes the password field on the wp-admin login page and directs logins to a mobile app with its own authentication on your smartphone.

On two sites, it's working fine and the password field is removed by the JS script. On the third site, which as far as I can tell is configured the same as the others, the password field is NOT removed. When I use the developer console in Chrome (latest stable) it throws up the error in the title when it's trying to load JQuery.

I have changed my Cache plugin to the same as the other sites (W3-Total Cache) and I have created wp-admin/php.ini with max_input_vars = 3000 because I saw someone else had used this to fix this error.

It hasn't worked.

Does anyone have any clues as to what more info I can give you to narrow down why this is happening? Or even where I can start looking?

This is happening in all browsers so it's not browser extensions causing it; I just chose to do the debugging in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys this is very strange but:

I am using Chrome as my default browser; and it worked on two other sites. In Chrome. But installing the latest JRE from Java dot com fixed it. For all browsers. I have no idea how that can be - but it is.

Thank you to anyone who was thinking about answering.